# IComparable<T>.CompareTo compares with null in Sort

Tags: c#, sorting, compareto, icomparable

I want to sort a list with the help of `IComparable<T>.CompareTo` for a type `T` called `Path`. I wrote

```
var shortest = new List<Path>();
//Fill shortest with elements != null
if (shortest.Contains(null))
      throw new System.Exception("Path is null");
shortest.Sort();
if (shortest.Contains(null))
      throw new System.Exception("Path is null");
```

To my surprise, the method

```
    int IComparable<Path>.CompareTo(Path other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return -1;

        if (!other.valid)
            return 1;

        if (pfad.Count() > other.pfad.Count())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (pfad.Count() < other.pfad.Count())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (length > other.length)
                return -1;
            else
                return 1;

        }

    }
```

from the class

```
 public class Path : IComparable<Path>
```

is called from `Sort()` with `other==null`. I am even more surprised that in the first code-block, the *second exception* is thrown, meaning that `shortest` contains a null value after the sort and not before.

Comment: Do you have a custom equality comparer?
Does your list of paths contain a null value?

Comment: there is a similar question on SO..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189750/sorting-icomparable-objects-some-of-which-are-null

Comment: I do not see the similarity. My question is: Why does Sort compare some value to null if my list never contains the value null?

Comment: Are you asking why `IComparable` needs to be able to compare to `null` or why your code seems to be sorting a list that contains a `null` item when it should be throwing an exception?

Comment: The second thing: If the list does not contain null, why does Sort() call CompareTo with other==null ?

Comment: How do you know that the CompareTo comparing with null is from the `Sort` and not from the `Contains`?

Comment: Does Path implement `IEquatable` and/or `IComparable`?  If so, please add the implementation(s) to your question.

Comment: @Servy would `Contains` call `IComparable.CompareTo`?  I think it just calls `IEquatable.Equals`.

Comment: I added some code to make the situation clearer

Comment: @DStanley This seems to be demonstrating that it's using `CompareTo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CompareTo` function is broken. It doesn't return `0` when an object is compared to itself and it always returns `1` when two objects with `valid == false` are compared. So there might be two objects`a` and `b` with `a.CompareTo(b) == 1` and `b.CompareTo(a) == 1` and this might lead to `Sort()` behave strangely.

Also, as already noted in the other answer, it should return `1` if `other == null`. (shouldn't really matter when the list doesen't contain `null`)

Comment: You're right. I still do not understand the behaviour of the sort function, but if I rewrite it using Sort(Comparison<T>), it works.

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot explain why Sort needs to compare to null, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) of IComparable.CompareTo explicitly states:

> By definition, any object compares greater than (or follows) null, and two null references compare equal to each other.

As such, whatever the reason is, the implementation of CompareTo has to follow this and the other rules to ensure compatibility with Sort() et al.

Comment: `"the implementation of CompareTo has to follow this"`, well, no, it doesn't.  Nothing prevents you from violating that; it's just a convention, not a requirement (and a rather poor convention at that).

Comment: Except library methods that use CompareTo often assume that they follow these conventions and may therefore behave unexpectedly if such is not the case. As such, you don't _have to_ follow them per se, but not doing so may lead to issues with said methods.

Comment: I've never come across a problem as a result of this.  There may be certain implementations of say, sort, or whatever other algorithm using comparisons, that may not call `CompareTo` at all on null values, and instead assume that null is "first", in which case it wouldn't *matter* what your solution did.  If they don't, then it will work just fine.